# Sybase SQL using French character

Tags: sql, character, sybase

I have a local Sybase database. This is a dbf file on my computer. This Sybase database holds string values with French characters, like "é".
The problem I have is that I can not find any values that have a "é" character in the string. 
The values are present in the table. I know this, because when I do not apply any restriction and select all records, I can see the values that hold an "é" character in their strings.

Example:

```
Select Column from SybasteTable
where Column = 'Fench é letters'
```

If I apply this restrictions, no records can be found even though records exists for this column.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not entirely clear to me. But if I am not mistaken you are looking for a way to select all rows with the é char inside it.  
IF that is the case try this query

```
SELECT [columnName] FROM [tableName]
WHERE [columName] SIMILAR TO '[a-e]'
```

Where [columnName] is the name of your column and [tableName] the name of your table

If I misunderstood your question, and you are looking for something else. could you please clarify your question or rephrase it.

EDIT:
replaced like clause with SIMILAR TO which should get all the accented chars between and including a - e.

Comment: Thank you for replying to my question. Yes, if you try to find a certain value, you can type "ColumnName" = 'French é'. I am talking about SYBASE SQL on a local SYBASE database. That is why this does not work for me because SYBASE does not understand é. Therefore I would like to know if anyone else had encountered this problem and if they have a solution for this issue.

Comment: after doing a little bit of research I found the `SIMILAR TO` clause, could you try the edit I made and see if that works?

Comment: Thx for replying. Unfortunately this also doesn't work. Is there a way in sql to replace all the e characters with an accent with a normal e character? Example: Replace the last character with an e in the word "visibilité". The tricky part is that it has to be dynamic, so applicable to every word without knowing where the character is situated in the word itself.